# JQuery $('tag') returns undefined in IE 11 (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following script

```
var sw_version_field = $('input[title$="SW version"]');
var sw_version_value = sw_version_field.val();
```

In Chrome `sw_version_field.val()` returns the value of the input field (an empty string eventually), but in IE11 the debugger throws an exception "Unable to get property 'val' of undefined or null reference".

I checked that jQuery is referenced with this script and the "hello" message is shown in both the browsers.

```
  window.onload = function() {
   if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Hello!");
   } else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
     alert("Error: jQuery wasn't properly load.");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i'm using jquery.2.1.0.min.js

Comment: Are there any errors in the console in IE11?

Comment: I get only this: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'val' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: can you reproduce in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Why use `window.onload` when jQuery provides `$.ready()`. Also, where in your page are both of those blocks of code? Is the first one in a `$.ready()` or `window.onload` function?

Comment: I solved the issue... AdBlock was interfering somehow. Uninstalled it and now it works like a charm. I think the question may be misleading now. Should I remove it?

Comment: I can't see that this will help others in the future, so I recommend removing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue uninstalling AdBlock for IE.